# Bootstrap form inline make input full width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div className="form-inline">
    <label>1.</label><br />
    <input type="text" className="form-control" />
</div>
```

Using bootstrap, why when I do input 100% the form will break? 
https://jsfiddle.net/bdw9eyme/

How to make label and input to be at same line and input will fill the rest of the screen?

Comment: Post rest of the form.

Comment: @Dražen what else u need? I just ask why the label and the input cant be same line.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use a `br` to create a break here, you can use CSS for that. Also you should either nest your `input` in the `label`, or use the `for` attribute with the `label` to link to an `id` on the `input`.

Making the row `flex` with the `input` set to `flex-grow: 1` will put the `input` by the `label` text, and make the `input` grow to take up the available space.

```css
input {
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin-left: 1em;
}
.fw {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.8.0/bootstrap-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div className="form-inline">
  <label class="fw">1. <input type="text" className="form-control"></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

i think this is what you're looking for

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-xs-2">1.</label>
  <div class="col-xs-10">
  <input class="form-control" type="text"/>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```